# Undefined reference when compiling camera_info_manager

Tags: ros, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm compiling camera_info_manager on Ubuntu 13.10 (armhf) and receiving undefined reference to camera_calibration_parsers::readCalibration.

See details below:

```
$ catkin_make_isolated --pkg camera_info_manager --install
....
==> Processing catkin package: 'camera_info_manager'
==> Building with env: '/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_info_manager'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_info_manager'
[ 33%] Built target gtest
[ 66%] Built target camera_info_manager
Linking CXX executable /home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_info_manager/lib/camera_info_manager/unit_test
/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_info_manager/lib/libcamera_info_manager.so: undefined reference to `camera_calibration_parsers::readCalibration(std::string const&, std::string&, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_info_manager/lib/libcamera_info_manager.so: undefined reference to `camera_calibration_parsers::writeCalibration(std::string const&, std::string const&, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_info_manager/lib/camera_info_manager/unit_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/unit_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'camera_info_manager': 
  Command '/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

What is funny that I remember that I had the same issue when I was compiling for Raspberry Pi and resolved it somehow, but it seems I can't remember how.

Any idea is appreciated.

Edit: camera_calibration_parses package is installed, that was the first thing I checked
Edit2: just realized that last time I raised a ticket in github against camera_info_manager, but then the issue got resolved on its own, so I just reopen the ticket. See make verbose output on the link: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/issues/23

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139246/undefined-reference-when-compiling-camera_info_manager/) by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-12**:
It looks like camera_info_manager tries to link against camera_calibration parsers: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/blob/hydro-devel/camera_info_manager/CMakeLists.txt#L23
Can you add a "message()" to the cmake lists to check the value of ${camera_calibration_parsers_LIBRARIES}?

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-03-12**:
Thanks, that helped - see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just managed to solve the issue after @jbinney asking me to add message() to the cmakelists file. As soon as I have added that the compile did run through fine.
It looks the issue was that the first time when I tried to compile camera_info_manager then some of the prerequisites were missing, so I went and installed them including camera_calibration_parsers and came back to re-try

```
catkin_make_isolated --pkg camera_info_manager --install
```

but the error was still there like camera_calibration_parsers wouldn't be installed. As soon as I modified the cmakelists file the compile did find it.
So the issue simply was that the dependencies are not listing camera_calibration_parsers, so when it gets added you need to trigger the recreation of the make file. Blah.

---

Originally posted by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) with karma: 218 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2018-01-04**:
What `message()`means? How am I supposed to add it on the CMakeLists?